# How to determine several minimum in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, min, enumerate

I have a list with several minimum:

```
some_list = [1,4,6,4,1,7]
```

Is there a built-in function or any smart solution to get the index of the minimums?

```
result = [0,4]
```

I made it like this so far, but I prefer a shorter/easier to read the solution.

```
 min = 10**10
 result = [] 
 for i in range(len(some_list)):
        if some_list[i] < min:
            min = some_list[i]
            result = [i]
        elif some_list[i] == min:
            result.append(i)
```

Comment: `min = 10**10` is _bad_ in two ways. First, you assume that your largest element is smaller than 10**10 (are you sure?) Second, you overwrite the built-in function `min()`. Consider writing as `myMin=max(some_list)+1`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

```
some_list = [1,4,6,4,1,7]
minimum=min(some_list)
index=[idx for idx,val in enumerate(some_list) if val==minimum]
# [0,4]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [13]: import numpy as np                                                     

In [14]: values = np.array([1,4,6,4,1,7])                                       

In [15]: np.where(values==values.min())                                         
Out[15]: (array([0, 4]),)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use List Comprehension to find all indexes of an item in list. Hope this is more simple.

```
some_list = [1,4,6,4,1,7]
result = [ i for i in range(len(some_list)) if some_list[i] == min(some_list) ]
print(result)
```